# Set default time in trentrichardson timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i set default time in `trentrichardson timepicker`. I checked *trentrichardson.com* for the documentation, but the site is down. Any suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: could you please paste your code here?

Comment: @shin
jQuery('#div').timepicker({                                                controlType: 'select',                                                timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'});

Comment: @shin : I got it, No need to waste your time. Thanks for the response.

Comment: ,I got example from https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon

Comment: @shin : In github there is no documentation.

Comment: But there a lot of examples,Anyway happy to know problem is solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got it Working. :)

```
jQuery('obj').timepicker({
     controlType: 'select',
     timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
     hour: '05', 
     minute : '36'
});
```